# Is there a way to call a function n times per second while compensating for drift?

Tags: c

I've seen a lot of answers to very similar questions, but they all seem to resort to using something like a sleep(1/n) call at the end of a function or in some cases timing the function and calling sleep((1/n) - functionTime). Surely there is a better way to do this? Modern hardware has access to precise hardware timers that can send an interrupt to the CPU some known number of times per second, is there no way to take advantage of these timers to run a function such as a physics engine update a known, fixed number of times per second from user space code? What I would like to do in particular is, preferably in C or C++, define some function, let's call it foo(), and designate it to be called N times per second. I would want to be able to know that if M seconds have passed, foo will have been called N*M times assuming foo() ran in less than 1/N seconds on average.

Comment: Depends on the system you're running under. Regular OSes – no, nothing is ever _precise_. Realtime OSes, more like it.

Comment: Having made the function call at 'approximate' intervals, you can use the actual interval to update the physics engine. But in what time base? Wall time or processor time?

Comment: In general purpose operating systems, this can be very difficult to achieve.  And of course, it also depends on how big you want `n` to be.  Are you talking about tens, hundreds, thousands, millions?  One strategy for dealing with impreciseness is to run your update steps at a much higher frequency than the actual callbacks.  Then, when you do get the chance to update, you take the current clock time and figure out how many cycles to run since the last compute in order to update the system.  This can also be used in a "predictive" way (e.g. adjusting for calculated output latency)

Comment: Why do you need such precision? A physics engine will work just fine with (n+1) updates every second or even (2*n) updates (if your hardware can pull it). And (n-1) is not the end of the world either.

Comment: yes, that's called timer in all multithreading OSes. And no, you can't get more precise time with a normal OS, it's just a minimum period guarantee

Comment: That's a fair point, nothing running under something like Windows will actually be called *precisely* every 1/N seconds. What I mean to say is that I want to know that if M seconds have passed, foo() has been called N*M times.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to run as a timer interrupt handler (or interrupt service routine, ISR?), which often requires that you write a device handler (kernel level). (Though I think it sounds as if you don't actually need this type of precision.)

Comment: You mention a physics engine – you should engineer the engine to work correctly with a flexible timestep instead of hoping it gets scheduled at precise-enough intervals.

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity. What I want is to avoid drift in the number of times foo() has been called relative to the number of seconds that have passed.

Comment: If you wait (1/n) seconds after each call, some drift is likely. A well-designed program should not wait in this manner. Rather, schedule the calls to start at every (1/n) seconds of your system clock. This way, even if a call is delayed for some reason, it will not affect the timing of the next call.

Comment: I agree with your statement completely. Unfortunately, all guides I can find on *how* to run N times per second say to sleep(1/N) seconds. If you know how to schedule calls to start at every (1/n) seconds, that would be lovely as it is exactly the answer I am looking for.

Comment: "all guides I can find on how to run N times per second say to sleep(1/N) seconds". These guides are not good ;)

Comment: Would you be willing to point me to some good ones? My entire purpose in asking the question was that I have spent the last 8 hours looking for a good one. Technically my particular application would *probably* be just fine with sleeping 1/n seconds like the guides say, but doing so sets off every bad practice, there is definitely a better, safer, more robust way to do this alarm bell I have. I am fairly new to C, I've only been using it for a year or so, and I don't know how to schedule function calls in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard C API for scheduling calls.

You probably want to have a separate thread that runs every 1/Nth of a second.

In the pthreads world, this can be done with [`pthread_cond_timedwait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html). This function expects the *absolute* time to wake up. In addition, some other thread can wake it up using the condition variable if some unplanned update needs to be made.

In the Windows world you probably need one of the [`WaitFor<whatever>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/wait-functions) functions. They expect a *relative* timeout, so you want to convert absolute time to relative time-interval-from-now yourself. In this case, too, another thread is able to wake you up to perform an urgent update.

The absolute time you need is just the absolute time the previous call was scheduled for, plus 1/Nth of a second. The very first one can be set to the current time just before the call.